# Best approach to creating a search function using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a site what you can tag data in the database. Any piece of data can have unlimited tags if so needed.

I have a modal that is accessible from any page that presents a search box for you to enter the tags.

I want to take a user to a "Search Results" page and display them to the user.

My issue is... What is the best way to send the data to the search results page? There could be X tags entered and depending on the amount of characters, it could exceed some limits on the GET variables for some browsers.

Just not sure of the best approach for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Search should be done using `GET`.

Comment: I understand that... but my concern is if I do a search for 30 words and each word was 10 letters its at 300 characters just for the tags. Would it be best to limit the amount of tags you can search by? I just dont want the URL to get too long where it breaks something as I have read some browsers have limits for length of the URL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers had a discussion about that.  I'd say 300 characters is fine as the consensus was a URL under 2000 characters.  If it were applicable for you to store tags from their search, you could use cookies or session variables rather than submitting them all through GET.